# How to use Reflectable package in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, reflection, reflections

I am trying to run this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) using Dart not fllutter by fallowing the next steps:

1. Creating the main file as is given [here](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable/example)
2. creating a build.yaml:

> ```
> targets:
>   $default:
>     builders:
>       reflectable:
>         generate_for:
>           - main.dart
>         options:
>           formatted: true
> ```

3. updating the version in pubspec.yaml:

> ```
> name: advertisement_app
> description: A sample command-line application.
> version: 1.0.0
>
> environment:
>   sdk: '>=2.18.0 <3.0.0'
>
> dependencies:
>   parse_server_sdk: ^4.0.2
>   dartz: ^0.10.1
>   reflectable: 4.0.5
>
> dev_dependencies:
>   lints: 2.0.1
>   test: 1.24.1
>   build_runner: 2.3.3
>   built_value_generator: 8.4.4
> ```

4. Run the command:  `dart run build_runner build`

And I have the fallowing output:

```
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 527ms
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 83ms
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 567ms
[INFO] Running build completed, took 7ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 34ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 53ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)
```

Dose anyone know what exactly I am doing wrong and why is not building any files?

My structure:

```
.
├── build.yaml
├── main.dart
├── pubspec.lock
├── pubspec.yaml
└── TEST_REFLECTION.iml

0 directories, 5 files
```